# include QSsh in my project on Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5, sftp

I want to implement a simple SFTP client (upload, download, list and remove). I've found a solution here at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758121/howto-implement-sftp-with-qt-qnetworkaccessmanager-c/13534512#). The way to go is using QSsh in my project. I'm quite new to Qt and Qt Creator and I don't know hoy to proceed. I've compiled it with Qt Creator, but then I proceed to "make" and I get Makefile `Error 204: multiple target patterns Stop.` I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am ussing Qt5.

How I can include QSsh in my QtCreator project ?

Comment: It would probably be easier to use Qt as a front-end to the command line calls to sftp and scp.

Comment: @hank The main .pro file content this: `TEMPLATE = subdirs CONFIG += ordered SUBDIRS = \ src \ examples \ tests` but there are other .pro files in the project. Sources are here [QSsh](https://github.com/lvklabs/QSsh)

Comment: Thank you @Merlin069, I am trying that way, with psftp on windows (client side) and Open_SSH on linux (server side), but I can't controll sshd (from Open_SSH) with `QProcess` by now.

Comment: " I can't controll sshd (from Open_SSH) with QProcess" - If this is a problem, please post your code and we can see if there's an obvious issue there.

Comment: hi have u figured out how to use QSsh in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I do this using libssh. Very straight forward. https://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutor_sftp.html

Don't forget to add your sftp server into known hosts in your system.

```
ssh-keyscan -H mysftpserver.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Example code:

```
#include "sftpuploader.h"
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libssh/sftp.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <QFile>

int verify_knownhost(ssh_session session)
{
    int state, hlen;
    unsigned char *hash = NULL;
    char *hexa;
    char buf[10];

    state = ssh_is_server_known(session);

    hlen = ssh_get_pubkey_hash(session, &hash);
    if (hlen < 0)
        return -1;

    switch (state)
    {
    case SSH_SERVER_KNOWN_OK:
        break; /* ok */

    case SSH_SERVER_KNOWN_CHANGED:
        fprintf(stderr, "Host key for server changed: it is now:\n");
        ssh_print_hexa("Public key hash", hash, hlen);
        fprintf(stderr, "For security reasons, connection will be stopped\n");
        free(hash);
        return -1;

    case SSH_SERVER_FOUND_OTHER:
        fprintf(stderr, "The host key for this server was not found but an other"
                        "type of key exists.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "An attacker might change the default server key to"
                        "confuse your client into thinking the key does not exist\n");
        free(hash);
        return -1;

    case SSH_SERVER_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find known host file.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "If you accept the host key here, the file will be"
                        "automatically created.\n");
        /* fallback to SSH_SERVER_NOT_KNOWN behavior */

    case SSH_SERVER_NOT_KNOWN:
        hexa = ssh_get_hexa(hash, hlen);
        fprintf(stderr,"The server is unknown. Do you trust the host key?\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Public key hash: %s\n", hexa);
        free(hexa);
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            free(hash);
            return -1;
        }
        if (strncasecmp(buf, "yes", 3) != 0)
        {
            free(hash);
            return -1;
        }
        if (ssh_write_knownhost(session) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error %s\n", strerror(errno));
            free(hash);
            return -1;
        }
        break;

    case SSH_SERVER_ERROR:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s", ssh_get_error(session));
        free(hash);
        return -1;
    }

    free(hash);
    return 0;
}

bool upload(const QString &localFile,
                          const QString &dest,
                          const QString &host,
                          const QString &username,
                          const QString &passwd)
{
    bool retVal = false;

    QFileInfo info(localFile);

    m_localFilename = info.canonicalFilePath();
    m_remoteFilename = dest + "/" + info.fileName();

    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    int port = 22;
    int rc;
    sftp_session sftp;
    sftp_file file;
    int access_type;
    int nwritten;
    QByteArray dataToWrite;
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;

    QFile myfile(m_localFilename);

    if(!myfile.exists())
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: File doesn't exist " << m_localFilename;
        return retVal;
    }

    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if(my_ssh_session == NULL)
    {
        return retVal;
    }

    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host.toUtf8());
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Error connecting to localhost: " << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: SSH connected";
    }

    // Verify the server's identity
    // For the source code of verify_knowhost(), check previous example
    if (verify_knownhost(my_ssh_session) < 0)
    {
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: verify_knownhost failed";
        return retVal;
    }

    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, username.toUtf8(), passwd.toUtf8());
    if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Error authenticating with password: " << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Authentication sucess";
    }

    sftp = sftp_new(my_ssh_session);
    if (sftp == NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Error allocating SFTP session:" << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }

    rc = sftp_init(sftp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Error initializing SFTP session:", sftp_get_error(sftp);
        sftp_free(sftp);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }

    access_type = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;
    file = sftp_open(sftp, dest.toUtf8(), access_type, S_IRWXU);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Can't open file for writing:", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        sftp_free(sftp);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }

    if(myfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        dataToWrite = myfile.readAll();
    }

    nwritten = sftp_write(file, dataToWrite, dataToWrite.size());
    if (nwritten != dataToWrite.size())
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Can't write data to file: ", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        sftp_close(file);
        sftp_free(sftp);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }

    rc = sftp_close(file);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Can't close the written file:" << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        sftp_free(sftp);
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        return retVal;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "SFTPUploader: Success";
        retVal = true;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```